# Open device gallary for view only

Tags: android, gallery

I find this code here to open the gallery from my own btn:

```
btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 0);
    }
});
```

It works, but when I click on a photo it exit the viewer.

I guess it because the "createChooser".

How can I change it to only view the photos and not to choose them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is impossible.

1. If you had access to a full class name of an activity to start the Gallery app you could call it as you usually do it `Activity.startActivity(Context context, Class clazz)`. But Gallery classes is an internal API which you have no direct access to.
2. Well, Gallery app is accessible via throwing an appropriate `Intent` like the one in your sample code. By setting action name `intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)` you request the behavior you've got (browse all images, select one, get back to the caller activity with a uri of a selected image). There is also another possible action `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`, and if set with a uri of an image it causes Gallery to show that image for you. But that's all we can request from Gallery (there are no other predefined actions to suit your needs - just to browse images).

So, a way out is to create your own custom image browser activity.

Comment: Hi Arhimed, 10x for your answer. Are you sure that there is no other way but implement custom image browser? I already made btn that opens the default dailer and another btn that opens sms default activity. Why it's so hard/impossible to open the gallary browser?

Comment: @David: It is not a problem to open the Gallery app (1) to select an image or (2) to view a desired image, but there is no such an option to start it just for browsing. At least I did not find how to do that.